# Как обрабатывать нажатие по элементам NavigationView android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-drawer

Я пробовал уже всё.

navigation_menu.bringToFront()

Сам view стоит в самом самом низу активити

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
      app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

setNavigationItemSelectListener тоже пробовал:

```
navigation_menu.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    Log.d("TESTTAG", "Test")
    return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener if (it.itemId == R.id.menuToHome) {
        val action = ProjectNavGraphDirections.actionGlobalProfileFragment()
        navController.navigate(action)
        true
    } else if(it.itemId == R.id.menuLogout) {
        User.logOut()
        true
    } else {
        it.onNavDestinationSelected(navController)
    }
}
```

И это тоже уже пробовал, она создаёт новое меню в toolbar'е, справа появляются три точки

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return if (item.itemId == R.id.termsAndConditions) {
        val action = NavGraphDirections.actionGlobalTermsFragment()
        navController.navigate(action)
        true
    } else {
        item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Весь код активити:

```
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentResultListener
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController
import com.example.app.model.User
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.util.zip.Inflater

class MainNavigation : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfig: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        User.pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        User.startActivity()

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.project_nav_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.main, R.id.managerMain),
            drawer_layout
        )

        navigation_menu.bringToFront()
        navigation_menu.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            Log.d("TESTTAG", "Test")
            return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener if (it.itemId == R.id.menuToHome) {
                val action = ProjectNavGraphDirections.actionGlobalProfileFragment()
                navController.navigate(action)
                true
            } else if(it.itemId == R.id.menuLogout) {
                User.logOut()
                true
            } else {
                it.onNavDestinationSelected(navController)
            }
        }
        if(User.isAuth) {
            navigation_menu.menu.findItem(R.id.menuLogout).isVisible = true
        }

        setupToolBar()
        setupBottomToolBar()
    }

    private fun setupToolBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)
        navigation_menu.setupWithNavController(navController)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu) 
        // Работает, но создаёт другое меню в правом верхнем углу экрана, ни как не взаимодействуя с NavigationView
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        Log.d("TESTTAG", "Test")
        return if (item.itemId == R.id.menuToHome) {
            val action = ProjectNavGraphDirections.actionGlobalProfileFragment()
            navController.navigate(action)
            true
        } else if(item.itemId == R.id.menuLogout) {
            User.logOut()
            true
        } else {
            item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfig) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Разметка активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".MainNavigation">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#68A633"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:theme="@style/App.toolbar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingEnd="25dp"
                android:text="..."
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/project_nav_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/project_nav_graph" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="26dp"
            android:paddingRight="26dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/navToSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingStart="21dp"
                    android:text="Поиск"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_medal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/navToBasket"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_handbag" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/navToAccount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем так и не нашёл решение своей проблемы, создал новый проект с NavigationView в студии и даже там нет никакого обработчика нажатий. Но нашёл всё-таки нашёл весьма странное, но рабочие решение, мне оно кажется даже более удобным чем setNavigationItemSelectedListener и уж тем более onOptionsItemSelected.

```
navigationMenu.menu.findItem(R.id.menuId).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    /*что-то делается*/
    return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
}
```